# Apache Camel Receiving Mail with empty Message Body (javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart)

Tags: apache-camel, mime

I got a problem with a camel route which should receive mails from IMAP and send them as a jms message to a queue (ActiveMQ). The mail body of some mails is missing.
While in most cases everything runs fine, in some cases the body hust contains: "javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@xx123x1".

The route simplified looks like this:

```
from("imaps://imap.....")
.convertBodyTo(String.class)
.to("jms:aQueue");
```

Can someone help me, finding out how I can reach that the body does not get lost?

Best wishes,
sitnam

Answer (score 0):

The MimeMultipart means that you have a mail message with more than one part.

Try to create a custom processor and look what's inside the MimeMultipart object.

here you find how to create a processor:
http://camel.apache.org/processor.html

Comment: I already got some Processors inside my routes. It seems that it depends on the attachments. I figured out, that this behaviour just happens when the mail got an attachment.

Comment: That's exactly what I tought

Comment: Cast to MimeMultipart and extract the content

Comment: the objecttype of that mails is already multipart my problem is to extract the content

Comment: i can save the attachments BUT i want to receive the mail body